# How find correct Ip for connection Client/Server Qt?

Tags: qt, server, find, ip, client

I created two Qt apps: one client and one server.
I use them to send some data for handle a remote device.
If I am in localhost I haven't issues about them, but when i search to connect them by internet i don't know how to find correct Ip server to connect Socket Client.
How i can find this ip node? 
Is there a class to find It?

Comment: You need the external ip address of the system. You may need to change your firewall for the communication to happen. If this is MS windows you will likely need UAC elevation to allow your program to listen.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot find it automatically, if this is what you're asking about.
In real life you would deploy your server on some publicly accessible host, give it a domain name (important part as your host can change the IP address at any time) and connect the client via the DNS domain.

However if you're just playing around and you want to show to the world that your app works, specifying the IP address of the server in your client code would be perfectly fine (assuming you're running both the server and the client in the same network).

In that case, if you're running mac/linux run the command `ifconfig` (or just `ip` depending on the distribution). On Windows you can run the command `ipconfig`. Both windows and linux will give you a similar output resembling this:
[image]

Pay attention to the network adapters. There can potentially be many of them. You may have some emulated adapters if you have docker or VMWare, you may have the wireless adapters if you have a WiFi card, and then the ethernet adapters if your computer can connect to the the internet with an ethernet cable. Each of these adapters specifies a different IPv4 address. You want to pick the one that is connected to the same network as your client. So for instance if both your server machine and your client running machine are connected to the same wifi, you pick the address from the `Wireless LAN adapter`